# Populate a list of links through powershell

Tags: powershell, splistitem, url

I have my webapp, my webs and a list created. My point is that I would like to populate my lists with values at the time of my deployment, which is done thanks to a powershell script.

So I would like to write a generic function to add items to a list, in a particular folder at deployment time. This function seems to work, but when it comes to add a link in the list, I have an error.

I have a list "Useful Links", which template is `Links`. In the script, where $list contains my list, and where $folder is my root folder, I wrote this :

```
$newItem = $list.Items.Add($folder.ServerRelativeUrl, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::File)
$urlValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue
$urlValue.Url = "http://MyUrl.com"
$urlValue.Description = "This is an awesome description"
$newItem["Url"] = $urlValue
```

And then I get this error :

```
Unable to index into an object of type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.
At line:1 char:11
+ $newItem[ <<<< "Url"] = $urlValue
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Url:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex
```

I tried with several cases for Url ("URL", "url", "Url"), and different types of value (`SPFieldURLValue`, `string`). But nothing works.

Besides, I noticed that when I populate the list from the website interface, when I try to examine items from sharepoint manager, or from powershell, this "Url" attribute is not set, so I wonder where and how to persist a Url in Sharepoint ...

EDIT -------

There were two issues :

- You must set the "URL" attribute (`$item["URL"] = $urlValue`)
- The $urlValue.Url must **ABSOLUTELY** be formatted as a URL (start with `http://`), otherwise you get the same error, and that's what lead me here in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$urlValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue("")
$urlValue.Description = "This is an awesome description"
$urlValue.Url =  "http://MyUrl.com"
$item["URL"] = $urlValue
$item.update()
```

Reference: http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2011/10/add-item-to-sharepoint-links-list.html

Comment: I already tried that, but without updating. These was the missing piece. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/KunaalKapoor/archive/2012/07/10/modify-link-hyperlinkurl-field-using-powershell.aspx). It seems that the expected value is a comma separated string.

```
$url = "http://url, description";
$newItem["Url"] = $url
```

Comment: I 've seen that piece of information somewhere, but it seems to me that I've already tried that one. I'll give it a try as soon as I can. Anyway, thank you for the tip!